# Metric Learning vs Similarity Learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, metrics, similarity, ranking

I struggle to find any comprehensive explanations about Similarity Learning. From what I have gathered it is the same as Metric learning, except it attempts to learn a similarity function rather than a metric.

Can anyone please clarify the difference between them? 
Any links or sources would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you found that is comprehensible but not sufficiently comprehensive?  The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_learning) covers it quite well.

Comment: So I understand that both attempt to learn a metric or similarity function that can relate or distinguished two objects. 
I however dont understand the difference in the concepts of metric and similarity. It feels like they are almost the same measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most (all?) purposes, metric learning is a subset of similarity learning.  Note that, in common use, "similar" is roughly an inverse of "distance": things with a low distance between them have high similarity.  In practice, this is usually a matter of semantic choice -- a continuous transformation can generally make the two isomorphic.

A metric needs to follow certain rules; a similarity function has looser standards.  For instance, compare a full-length (say, 2 hours) movie `M` with a 20-minute animated reduction `A`.  A metric function `f` requires that `f(M, A) = f(A, M)`.  However, if you decide that the richness of the movie means that it shouldn't regard the cartoon as such close kin, you might input the pair of training triples

```
(A, M, 0.90)
(M, A, 0.15)
```

Another example would be with set similarity, measured by size and membership, but in a non-Euclidean fashion.

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4}
b = {3, 4, 5, 6}
c = {5, 6, 7, 8}
```

A similarity training would allow

```
(a, b, 2)
(b, c, 2)
(a, c, 10)
```

In this "world", `a` and `c` suffer a large penalty because they have nothing in common but set size.  `b` is close to each of them due to having half the elements in common.  This would give a metric function a headache, since it severely violates `subaddition`, the triangle inequality.

Does that help clear up the differences?

Comment: This does clear things up.
Is it correct if I say that a Similarity measure is a more abstract distance metric that can not be represented in a Euclidean space?

Comment: No: a similarity measure does not have to qualify as a distance metric.  "distance metric" is a hard-lined defined term.  That would be somewhat like saying that a general complex number is a "more abstract integer".

Comment: Yes, that is how I understood it, my wording might have been a little off regarding 'Similarity **is** a more abstract..'
Thank you

Comment: I saw that you are a editor of research papers and a deep learning engineer. I am currently working on a research paper on using deep similarity learning to predict football match outcomes and their rankings.

Just thought that you might be interested in the topic and the final product. If you are, let me know.

Comment: Good to know that we're on the same thought track; thanks.
Yes, I'd be interested in the research paper.  Post a link here when the time comes?